# getting the latest xx records with mongoose, How to order them?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get the last 20 records of user collection with mongoose:

```
User.find({'owner': req.params.id}).
sort(date:'-1').
limit(20).
exec(.....)
```

This works well, show the last 20 items.

But the items inside the array are sorted from the most recent to the oldest, Is there any way to reverse this with mongoose?

Thanks

Comment: would you mind to share your collection as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do this with an aggregation, such as this:

```js
db.user.aggregate[(
  { $match : {"owner" : req.params.id}},
  { $sort : {"date" : -1}},
  { $limit : 20},
  { $sort : {"date" : 1}}
])
```

Notes on this aggregation:

- The first three parts do the same job as the Find in your question
- The fourth part applies a further sort, which re-orders the returned 20 records from oldest to most recent
- I have written it in native [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) syntax; you will need to adjust the code to generate the same [aggregation from Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate).

---

Update: I think this is *not* possible with a [find() with cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods), because you would need two different `sort()` operations. But, MongoDB does *not* treat them as a sequence of independent operations; the docs give an example of methods written in one order — `sort().limit()` — being equivalent to the opposite order — `limit().sort()`, showing that the order cannot be relied upon as meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Find total and select only latest 20 , may be this is not effective way you found , but this will solve your problem.

```
 User.count({'owner': req.params.id},function(err,count){

  if(count){

    var skipItem=count-20;
    User.find({'owner': req.params.id}).
    .skip(skipItem)
    .limit(20)
    .sort(date:'1').
    exec(.....)

  }

});
```

Comment: It's not clear how this query _selects the last-dated 20 documents_, but returns them in _ascending date order_ as the OP requested?

Answer (score -1):

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: {
       'owner': req.params.id
    }},
    { $unwind: '[arrayFieldName]' },
    { $sort: {
        '[arrayFieldName]': -1/1,
         'date':-1
    }}
])
```

Comment: I don't think there's any need for an unwind here; the OP never mentioned any array field in their data.